# Manipulation Table

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting

I have a table 9x10000, and I need to manipulate in the following way:
if one element of the fifth line is equal to zero, the corresponding columns has to be deleted, otherwise it has to be left.

I tried with an if and drop inside a for loop, but it does not work.
Many thanks

Comment: One way is to apply this composed function to your data: `Composition[Transpose, 
 DeleteCases[{_, _, _, _, 0, _, _, _, _}], Transpose]`

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[f]
f = Transpose @ Delete[Position[#[[5]], 0]] @ Transpose @ # &;
```

***Example:***

```
SeedRandom[1234]
table = RandomInteger[5, {9, 10}];

MatrixForm[MapAt[Style[#, Blue] &, #, {5, All}] /. 
    Style[0, _] :> Style[0, Red, Bold]] & @ table
```

[image]

```
table2 = f @ table;
MatrixForm[table2]
```

[image]

Also

```
ClearAll[f2]
f2 = #[[All, Complement[Range@Length@#, Flatten@Position[#, 0]] &@#[[5]]]] &;

f2 @ table == f @ table
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Comment: Thanks...works!

Answer (score 1):

Two variants using Position and streamlining a bit.

Kindly stealing kglr's matrix,

```
SeedRandom[1234]
table = RandomInteger[5, {9, 10}];
```

With `Fold` and `Drop`:

```
SetRow = 5;
RemCol = Flatten[Position[table[[SetRow]], 0]];
output = Fold[Drop[#1, None, {#2}] &, table, Reverse[RemCol]]
```

With `MapThread`

```
SetRow = 5;
RemCol = Position[table[[SetRow]], 0];
output = MapThread[Delete, {table, ConstantArray[RemCol, Length[table]]}]
```

I do not know about efficiency, and I believe many ways that use Apply or custom functions can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Using kglr's data

```
SeedRandom[1234];

m = RandomInteger[5, {9, 10}];

p = Prepend[All] /@ Position[m[[5]], 0]
```

{{All, 2}, {All, 8}}

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
ReplaceAt[_ :> Nothing, p] @ m // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Using `MapAt`

```
MapAt[Nothing, p] @ m // MatrixForm
```

(* same result *)

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom[1234];

m = RandomInteger[5, {9, 10}];
```

---

Grabbing kglr's data and using `ReplacePart`:

```
p = Position[m[[5]], 0];

ReplacePart[#1, #2 -> Nothing] & @@@ Thread[{#, Array[p &, Length@#]}] &@m;

% // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
SeedRandom[1234];
table = RandomInteger[5, {9, 10}]; (* Using @kglr's data *)

f = If[#[[5]] == 0, Nothing, #] &;

res = ArrayReduce[f, table, 1] // Transpose;
MatrixForm /@ {table, res}
```

---

[image]